# iterating over a list and deleting elements in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function that takes a list and returns a new list. A new list is created by deleting element if there is smaller element in the tail of list. For example:
`minimum [3, 2, 5, 2, 5]` should return `[2,2,5]`

```
minimum (x : xs)
   | null xs
      = []
   | otherwise
      = let
         minelem (x : xs) n
            =
               if x < head(xs)
                  then drop n (x : xs) --how to go to the end of the list here? 
                  else --and here?
      in minimum (x : xs) 1

minimum _
   = []
```

It is a part of a homework. Please help to finish this function.

Comment: Were you given that structure and asked to complete it, or was that what you came up with so far in your attempts to solve the problem?

Comment: it is what i came up with. You can change it, but please remember that i am learning elementary haskell. Thanks

Comment: The `| null xs = []` means you produce `[]` for all inputs. Probably.

Comment: The key observation is that the first element of the list returned by `minimum` (if it's not null) is the minimum of that list. So you do your recursive call.... (Btw, do you have to call your function `minimum`? There's already a function of that name in the Prelude.)

Comment: please write the code, if it is not difficult to you. I'd very happy, because i really do not know how to finish this task.

Comment: @Bob This is your homework. If you do not learn how to write it yourself, you are wasting your time taking the course.

Comment: as really do not understand recursion properly and want o learn it. so, how can i learn it without the code?

Comment: copying other folks' code won't do it.  you need to try things.  start with smaller, easier tasks - for instance, you could write a function that just returns the minimum value from a list, as a single item, rather than trying to build the list.

Comment: the main problem is that i understand simple recursion, but complex recursion - not. I think that here could be use 2 for loop (recursion version).

Comment: Bob: if you had a minval() function that returned the minimum value of a list, would that help you finish the code?

Comment: no... i do not realize how to iterate over the list checking for min values

Answer (score 5):

I've left some details for you to fill in.

```
minimum' []       = []                     -- base case
minimum' (x : xs) = case minimum' xs of    -- recursive case
    []       -> ...
    (y : ys) -> ...                        -- clue: none of the ys are smaller than y
```